# Thread deadlock on simple operations in pry

Tags: ruby, multithreading, deadlock, pry

[Note: I "fixed" this problem by creating and using a new gemset. I'm still curious why the problem occurred but it is no longer blocking me.]

[I am aware that there is a similar issue at [Deadlock in Ruby join()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925001/deadlock-in-ruby-join/32241707#32241707), but I have tried the timeout parameter suggested there and it does not help. I suspect there is a pry-specific problem not covered there.]

I am getting the error below when running the code below, but only when  executed within a pry session. This code has not been changed and has been working fine for quite a while, and I have no idea why it's an issue just now. I am using pry version 0.11.3 on Ruby 2.5.1. Also, this code works fine when pasted into pry; it's not working in my wifi-wand application that launches pry in the context of one of its objects (`gem install wifi-wand` to install, https://github.com/keithrbennett/wifiwand is the project page).

```
domains = %w(google.com  baidu.com)
puts "Calling dig on domains #{domains}..." if @verbose_mode

threads = domains.map do |domain|
  Thread.new do
    output = `dig +short #{domain}`
    output.length > 0
  end
end

threads.each(&:join)


[1] pry(#<WifiWand::CommandLineInterface>)> ci
Calling dig on domains ["google.com", "baidu.com"]...
fatal: No live threads left. Deadlock?
3 threads, 3 sleeps current:0x00007fbd13d0c5a0 main thread:0x00007fbd13d0c5a0
* #<Thread:0x00007fbd14069c20 sleep_forever>
   rb_thread_t:0x00007fbd13d0c5a0 native:0x00007fff89c2b380 int:0
   /Users/kbennett/work/wifi-wand/lib/wifi-wand/models/base_model.rb:89:in `join'
   /Users/kbennett/work/wifi-wand/lib/wifi-wand/models/base_model.rb:89:in `each'
   /Users/kbennett/work/wifi-wand/lib/wifi-wand/models/base_model.rb:89:in `block in connected_to_internet?'
   /Users/kbennett/work/wifi-wand/lib/wifi-wand/models/base_model.rb:126:in `connected_to_internet?'
   /Users/kbennett/work/wifi-wand/lib/wifi-wand/command_line_interface.rb:264:in `cmd_ci'
```

Comment: Since this only happens using wifi-wand as you explained (and not when using pry itself): Could you explain how you start wifi-wand in your case? When i just do `wifi-wand -s` and enter your code (either directly or via `%edit`) it just works (if I am not mistaken) and shows `[#<Thread:0x00007ff82bafa200@(pry):5 dead>, #<Thread:0x00007ff82bafa0e8@(pry):5 dead>]` as legit result.

Comment: Thanks, Jay. I trigger that code by calling the `ci` (connected to Internet?) command (that is, typing just `ci[Enter]` on the pry command line). I'm not surprised thought that that works for you, because it has always worked for me too until today.

Comment: @JaySchneider I "fixed" the issue by creating a new (rvm) gemset and using it. It still seems crazy to me that it started going nuts today out of the blue, and I still wonder what happened, but it is no longer blocking me.

Comment: Ok this is good to hear.
If you still want to look into this, maybe provide your OSX version in the question. Although it doesn't seem to be related (since you got it working without changes here apparently), for me it worked with 10.13.3.
You could also try to remove gems from your old, broken gemset piece by piece to check for weird interactions.
But anyway, I am glad you could find a solution that works for now.

Comment: I'm using OS X 10.13.5. I uninstalled/reinstalled some gems one at a time in the default gemset, and the un/re-install of awesome_print fixed the problem. (!!!!!!)

Comment: Ok, congrats. So if you find out on which side the problem most likely is caused I guess that the developers of either gem will be supportive on github. Consider posting your results as an answer to your own question? Good luck further on!

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, the problem was fixed by uninstalling and reinstalling the `awesome_print` gem. I have no idea why.